# What is this game box easter egg in The Last of Us?

Tags: the-last-of-us

In **The Last of Us** at the Ranch House, there is a stack of boardgames with various references on them:

[image: Boardgames at Ranch]

I'm aware of what a lot of them are:

- The Game of Strife (Easter egg for The Game of Life)
- Tasker (Risk Easter egg?)
- Chess
- Checkers (not in image)
- Carcass Quest (Carcassonne Easter egg)

The only one I'm not sure of is the yellow box between Chess and Carcass Quest

Does any one recognize what game is this box referring to?

Here is a closer picture:

[image: Yellow box from the side]

Comment: This is not a question about video games.

Comment: I personally do not see how a question about fiction inside a video game is not a question about videogames. If someone wants to know about a videogame plot, they do not need to go to literature SE, and if a game features a cat, it does not mean that the question about that cat should be answered at pets SE. Some of these boardgames in question are not even real, how _possibly_ boardgames SE can help?

Comment: @Andrew Savinykh, Re "*how possibly boardgames SE can help?*", Questions seeking to identify board games are definitely [welcome](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) at B&CG SE, whether the source is a video game or not. They account for more than 3% of all questions. (This is independent of whether it's also acceptable here or not.)

Comment: Occasionally there are questions that are applicable to multiple sites.  Just because a question fits on one site does not mean it doesn't fit on another as well.

Comment: Our community recently discussed whether easter egg questions like this are on-topic: [Are questions about in-game jokes/references off-topic?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14876/28182)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is an Easter Egg that is directed towards the game [Jak and Daxter](https://jakanddaxter.fandom.com/wiki/Jak_and_Daxter_series), a game also by Naughty Dogs. While the character pose is blurry, it closely resembles the pose that is shown on the PS2 cover art. The Easter Egg also makes an appearance in Naughty Dog's [Uncharted 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNuRh.jpg).

[image: Jak and Daxter PS2]

Comment: You can also see the title on the box